# When i run my code it show error like this one i dont really what went wrong.FlutterError (setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

Exception has occurred.
FlutterError (setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.
This Obx widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the framework is already in the process of building widgets. A widget can be marked as needing to be built during the build phase only if one of its ancestors is currently building. This exception is allowed because the framework builds parent widgets before children, which means a dirty descendant will always be built. Otherwise, the framework might not visit this widget during this build phase.
The widget on which setState() or markNeedsBuild() was called was:
Obx
The widget which was currently being built when the offending call was made was:
MediaQuery)

```
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final HomeController homeController = Get.find();
  final String title;
  final db = DatabaseHelper();

  @override
  Widget build(context) {
    return Scaffold(
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
      body: CustomScrollView(shrinkWrap: true, slivers: [
        SliverAppBar(
          shadowColor: Colors.transparent,
          stretch: true,
          pinned: true,
          backgroundColor: Colors.white.withAlpha(0).withOpacity(0),
          flexibleSpace: ClipRect(
            child: BackdropFilter(
              filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 6, sigmaY: 6),
              child: Container(color: Colors.transparent),
            ),
          ),
          actions: [
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Get.toNamed('/temp');
              },
              child: const Text(
                "Today",
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 1, 132, 127), fontSize: 16),
              ),
            )
          ],
          title: Text(
            title,
            style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.teal),
          ),
        ),
        SliverPersistentHeader(
          pinned: true,
          delegate: MyDelegate(header()),
        ),
        adapter(sliverBuild()),
      ]),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          Get.toNamed('/addSchedule');
        },
        tooltip: 'Add New Schedule',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }

  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  Widget adapter(Widget widget) {
    return SliverToBoxAdapter(
      child: widget,
    );
  }

///////////////////////////////// sliverheader//////////////////////////////////
  Widget header() {
    List<String> tabs = ["S", "M", "T", "W", "T", "F", "S"];
    return ClipRect(
      child: BackdropFilter(
        filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 6, sigmaY: 6),
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.8).withAlpha(0),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              GridView.builder(
                itemCount: 7,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Obx(
                    () => Card(
                      elevation: 0,
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                      ),
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 4, right: 4),
                      color: homeController.isDay[index]
                          ? Colors.amber
                          : Colors.white,
                      child: InkWell(
                        splashColor: Colors.teal,
                        onTap: () {},
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: homeController.isDay[index]
                                      ? Colors.white
                                      : const Color.fromARGB(
                                          255, 188, 193, 205),
                                  fontSize: 20),
                              tabs[index],
                            ),
                            Text(homeController
                                .theDays()[index]
                                .toString()
                                .padLeft(2, '0'))
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
                gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                  crossAxisCount: 7,
                ),
                shrinkWrap: true,
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, top: 5),
                child: Row(children: [
                  const Text("Time",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 188, 193, 205),
                          fontSize: 16)),
                  const SizedBox(width: 100),
                  const Text("Subject",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 188, 193, 205),
                          fontSize: 16)),
                  const SizedBox(width: 130),
                  IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    splashColor: Colors.teal,
                    icon: const FaIcon(
                      FontAwesomeIcons.arrowDownWideShort,
                      color: Color.fromARGB(255, 188, 193, 205),
                    ),
                  )
                ]),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget subDetail(int index) {
    var shour = homeController.scheduleList[index].dateTimeRange!.start.hour
        .toString()
        .padLeft(2, '0');
    var sminute = homeController.scheduleList[index].dateTimeRange!.start.minute
        .toString()
        .padLeft(2, '0');
    var ehour = homeController.scheduleList[index].dateTimeRange!.end.hour
        .toString()
        .padLeft(2, '0');
    var eminute = homeController.scheduleList[index].dateTimeRange!.end.minute
        .toString()
        .padLeft(2, '0');
    var duration = homeController.scheduleList[index].dateTimeRange!.end
        .difference(homeController.dateTime.value)
        .inDays;
    if (duration < 0) {
      homeController.removeSchedule(homeController.scheduleList[index]);
    }
    return Row(
      children: [
        Column(children: [
          Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
              child: Text("$shour:$sminute",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black.withAlpha(180), fontSize: 16)),
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 10),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
            child: Text(
              "$ehour:$eminute",
              style: const TextStyle(
                  color: Color.fromARGB(255, 188, 193, 205), fontSize: 16),
            ),
          )
        ]),
        VerticalDivider(
          color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
          thickness: 2,
        ),
        Card(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
          shape:
              RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
          color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 230, 243, 242),
          child: SizedBox(
            height: 220,
            width: 280,
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, top: 10),
                      child: Text(
                        homeController.scheduleList[index].subject,
                        style: const TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                    ),
                    const Expanded(child: SizedBox(width: 160)),
                    PopupMenuButton(
                      onSelected: (value) {
                        if (value == 0) {
                          homeController.removeSchedule(
                              homeController.scheduleList[index]);
                        }
                      },
                      itemBuilder: (context) => const [
                        PopupMenuItem(value: 0, child: Text("Delete")),
                        PopupMenuItem(value: 1, child: Text("Update")),
                        PopupMenuItem(value: 2, child: Text("Extend")),
                      ],
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.more_vert),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 20),
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, top: 10),
                    child: Text(
                      homeController.scheduleList[index].chapter,
                      style: const TextStyle(
                          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 112, 112, 112),
                          fontSize: 18,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 60),
                Row(
                  children: [
                    const SizedBox(width: 10),
                    const Icon(
                      Icons.timer,
                      size: 18,
                    ),
                    Text("   $duration days left for the Chapter",
                        style: const TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 14,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            color: Color.fromARGB(255, 112, 112, 112)))
                  ],
                ),
                Row(
                  children: const [
                    SizedBox(width: 240),
                    Icon(Icons.radio_button_off,
                        size: 20, color: Color.fromARGB(255, 196, 196, 196)),
                  ],
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 10),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget sliverBuild() {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Obx(
          () => GridView.builder(
              gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                  crossAxisCount: 1),
              physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: homeController.scheduleList.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return subDetail(index);
              }),
        ),
        const SizedBox(height: 20)
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! It looks like the error is in another place. Is it possible to copy-paste the entire app into the question itself? You can strip it to the barebone so other users can reproduce the problem.

Comment: seems like issue is coming getx uses